# Catching handled exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

Hey:)
Is there any way to catch a *handled* exception globally?  I know we can catch unhandled exceptions with " AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException" and  "Application.ThreadException", but I would like to add some handling to the exceptions I already caught (such as writing to log, etc)

thanks

Answer (score 4):

In general, you probably want to catch exceptions at the lowest possible level in your code. The closer they're handed relative to where the exception occurs, the better chance that you have to fix the problem that caused them.

**If you *can't* take any corrective action at this level that has a hope of fixing the problem causing the exception, you *should not be handling it at all*.** Just let the exception bubble up, and handle it globally like you want.

That being said, if you've have *handled* the exception at a lower level, **the only way you're going to be able to catch it at a higher level is if you [*rethrow* it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex(v=VS.100).aspx)** from the `Catch` block at the lower level.
So, for example:

```
try
{
   //your code
}
catch (SomeException e)
{
   //take any relevant handling measures

   //rethrow the exception
   throw; 
}
```

Of course, this would technically mean that the exception is *unhandled* by this Try/Catch block at the lower level, but that's the only way you're going to have anything to catch at a higher level.

For more information on rethrowing exceptions, see:

- [Why Re-throw Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113565/why-re-throw-exceptions)
- http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/02/rethrowing-exceptions-and-preserving-the-full-call-stack-trace.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhcbs8fz.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can rethrow same exception and catch it in calling module / logging module and then log it.
For example :

```
private void DivideByZero()
{
try
{
    int x = 2/0;
}
cath(Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline(ex.ToString());
    throw;
}
}

void Main(string[] a)
{
    try
    {
       DivideByZero();
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        // write logging code here .. 
    }

}
```

Comment: Rethrowing means the exception *wasn't* handled.

Comment: @Brian, he wants to know how to catch "handled" exceptions so I showed him one possible way to do it. There may be other ways also.

Comment: no he says he wants to monitor the exceptions for logging, etc, not having his application blow up as a side effect.

Comment: @Albin, his first line is 'Is there any way to catch a handled exception globally?'

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not global exception event. That would be very dangerous, you would catch all sorts of internal exceptions from other modules that was not ment for public use. It would also potentially drown your logs with exceptions.

You should be more structured about your exception handling to achieve the same effect. Encapsulate the actual handling of exceptions and do minimal work in the actual catch block. Either by just have a "HandleException" method somewhere that you pass every exception too. You might also have a look at the [Exception Handling block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664698%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) in Enterprise library.

Comment: I understood that the Exception Handling block in Enterprise library can provide some sort of delegate that's being called in each "catch" block. Is that correct?